# Declaring types of old F77 functions and subroutines for Fortran 2003 code

Tags: fortran, fortran77, fortran95

We have a new Fortran 2003 code which calls and is linked to a Fortran 77 library (in an external package). Is there any way to write declarations for the F77 functions and subroutines in the external library in F2003, to ensure an error message is given if functions are called with the wrong argument types? One way would be to write wrappers for each function, but this seems a lot of work.

(Incidentally, the F77 code is actually wrappers for calling C code. Ideally it would be better to rewrite the C wrappers in F2003, but that's also a lot of work).

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Some compilers offer options to automatically generate (and check) interfaces for external procedures.

Comment: We're using gfortran for the new fortran code. The external functions are actually written in C but exported using the ancient cfortran.h interface library.

Comment: How easy would it be for you to throw away the FORTRAN wrappers and just interface directly with the C functions ?  Using the screamingly modern *interoperability with C* features of Fortran ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: probably the best idea, but there are a lot of functions and there is a bit of extra code in current fortran-ABI library which hides the C pointers away. Ideally I would have liked to keep the same API so existing code could just include the prototypes and it would be type checked.

Comment: You say "write declarations" and "write wrappers" in the question - to be clear what you want to do is "write interfaces".  Based on the accepted answer, it appears that your question was how to have those interfaces automatically generated?  Otherwise, manually authoring them is the obvious answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intel compiler, ifort, has the option -gen-interfaces. I think that this option does exactly what you need.
Unlike the gfortran compiler (which unfortunately does not have this feature), ifort costs money,
Perhaps you can get someone to run ifort -gen-interfaces once for your really old fortran77stuff?
I assume that the fortran77 code no longer changes, so the generated *__genmod.f90 can be used
and do not have to be generated time and again.

An alternative is to make a module:

```
     MODULE NOSTALGIA77
     CONTAINS
       include 'file1.f'
      ...
       include 'fileN.f'
     END MODULE NOSTALGIA77
```

Now when you compile the module and not the separate files, you can use the functions and subroutines
after adding USE NOSTALGIA77 to your Fortran2003-code, and the compiler will check the correctness of your calls.

Note: the example assumes that the fortran77 code contains only subroutines. If it contains other stuff as well
(BLOCK DATA and other things we don't want to remember), the module may be a little more difficult to make because
some stuff will come before the CONTAINS and some after. But it can still be done (and not in too much time).

Good luck!

---

Edit:

Perhaps https://shroud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ can help you. I did a few small tests (see https://shroud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendix-A.html).
What seemed to work is to put a few lines of your header files in a yaml file clibrary.yaml, each line preceded by '-decl':

```yaml
declarations:
- decl: void NoReturnNoArguments()
- decl: double PassByValue(double arg1, int arg2)
```

I suppose this yaml file can easily be constructed from your header files using sed, awk, python or whatever scripting language you like.
Next, all you run is shroud clibrary.yaml, and out comes a fortran module libray_mod, which you can include and then all your functions are available, and their usage is tested.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't make it clear that the F77 interface is actually C wrapped with cfortran. It has the F77 ABI, but there's no F77 code. It looks like: `FCALLSCSUB5(ffgkyl,FTGKYL,ftgkyl,FITSUNIT,STRING,PINT,PSTRING,PINT)`. This is a good answer otherwise, though.

Comment: @xioxox that does complicate things, I'll have a look but I don't expect to have a suitable answer

Comment: @xioxox I've added a suggestion that I think might work

Comment: Thanks - shroud looks very helpful